# How to do filtering data in UITableView like 'Recents' view in Phone application?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, filtering

I am planning to applied the feature like 'Recents' view in Phone application of iPhone. This view show option on the top, 'All' and 'Missed'. Default option is 'All' but if you tap 'Missed' option the entry in UITableView which aren't 'Missed call' will slide out and disappear. This is the good feature.

So I know you can help me by suggest or guide me some idea (any article is good too). I try to googling around but I couldn't find any good one.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean it's good as in it animates or it's able to do filtering? The filtering is just the result of some basic data management using predicates/sort descriptors/etc. that is really too broad for a question.

Check out [UITableView beginUpdates] and [UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:] and other similar selectors in the documentation for more information on making it animate.